# imagem não aparece por regra no .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, php-7

Tenho meu `.htaccess` da forma abaixo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -t [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
    RewriteRule ^.$ - [NC,L] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?localhost/mvc [NC]
    RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]

    ErrorDocument 400 http://localhost/mvc/400.php
    ErrorDocument 401 http://localhost/mvc/401.php
    ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/mvc/403.php
    ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/mvc/404.php
    ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/mvc/500.php

</IfModule>

php_value allow_url_fopen on
php_value allow_url_include on
php_flag mail_filter 0
```

Da forma que está, e creio que o *problema* esteja aqui:

```
RewriteRule ^.$ - [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**Não** estou conseguindo exibir `imagens` pois todo `link` precisa antes passar pela página `index.php` pela *regra* que estou usando.

Tentei colocar o **caminho absoluto** da imagem mas também não resolveu.

Meus objetos nesse `.htaccess` são:

1) Toda `requisição` chegar obrigatoriamente no **index.php**

2) Que as `imagens` apareçam normalmente (**NÃO** é erro de `link` pois quando desabilito no `.htaccess` as duas linhas supracitadas a `imagem` aparece no browser.)

3) Será que tem como otimizar esse `.htaccess`?